# How to add a todo in Vue.js only if vuelidate does not give an error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple operation that I would like to do:

Add a new todo item (the prop is called "newTodo") to my list only if vuelidate does not throw an `$v.newTodo.$error`

As you can see below, my solution within methods is this:

```
addTodo: function(newTodo) {
  if (this.$v.newTodo.$error === false) {
    this.todos.unshift(newTodo);
    this.newTodo = "";
  }
}
```

Another alternative to prevent at least empty todo inputs from being added to the list is this:

```
addTodo: function(newTodo) {
  if (!this.newTodo === "") {
    this.todos.unshift(newTodo);
    this.newTodo = "";
  }
}
```

But apparently all of this does not work. Currently, it displays the error message but I can still add a new todo even if the minLength requirement of 6 chars is not fulfilled.

**I am wondering where and how I can tell my todos about this condition**. Here is the relevant script in full:

```
<template>
<header>

<input
  class="todo-input-field"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Add a todo"
  v-model.trim="newTodo"
  :class="{ 'todo-input-warning': $v.newTodo.$error }"
  @keyup.enter="addTodo(newTodo)"
>

<div v-if="!$v.newTodo.$error">
  <p class="todo-input-warning" v-if="!$v.newTodo.minLength">Minimum length is 6 chars!</p>
</div>

</header>
</template>

<script>
...

data() {
return {
  newTodo: ""
}
},
methods: {
addTodo: function(newTodo) {
  if (this.$v.newTodo.$error === false) {
    this.todos.unshift(newTodo);
    this.newTodo = ""
  }
}
},
validations: {
newTodo: {
  required,
  minLength: minLength(6)
  }
}
}
</script>
```

I would expect to add a todo only if $error from vuelidate is false. The actual result is that I can add a todo no matter if $error is false or true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuelidate seems rough... This is how I was able to accomplish it - you are only allowed to add items if they are validated..

```js
Vue.use(window.vuelidate.default)
const {
  required,
  minLength
} = window.validators

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: '',
    addedItems: [],
  },
  validations: {
    text: {
      required,
      minLength: minLength(5)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    status(validation) {
      return {
        error: validation.$error,
        dirty: validation.$dirty
      }
    },
    add(v) {
      if (!v.$invalid) {
        this.addedItems.unshift(v.text.$model);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.dirty {
  border-color: #5A5;
  background: #EFE;
}

.dirty:focus {
  outline-color: #8E8;
}

.error {
  border-color: red;
  background: #FDD;
}

.error:focus {
  outline-color: #F99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate@0.7.4/dist/vuelidate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate@0.7.4/dist/validators.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div class="error" v-if="!$v.text.minLength">Item must have at least {{$v.text.$params.minLength.min}} letters.</div>
  </div>
  <input v-model="$v.text.$model" :class="status($v.text)">
  <button @click="add($v)">Add</button>
  <h3>Added Items:</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item,index) in addedItems">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <hr/>
  <hr/>
  <h4>Vuelidate Object:</h4>
  <pre>{{ $v }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to use JSFiddle. You can add a working example using the snippets tool in the answer editor.

Comment: @Soviut ... and what if I **want** to use JSFiddle?? I am already aware of the built in code snippet editor thing...

Comment: You're free to do so, but working examples tend to get more upvotes and external links can go dead. You've already written out all the code necessary to make a working snippet, it's pretty easy to just copy that to the snippet editor.

Comment: @Soviut ... I must admit, I do like the built in snippet editor.. I don't remember liking it this much prior to today.. Thanks for showing me the light!

Comment: Thanks, that's much better!

Comment: @Soviut ... you're the man/woman (whatever you are)!!! Also, how do you like PagerDuty? At my old, old job we used to use it - it was pretty awesome! So cool to interact with someone that works/worked there!! Cheers!